# Multiple program execute one after first one finished, python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using python, I need to call a program three times with different parameters. What I need is no parallel running these programs. Start a new program only after the previous one finish. How should I modify the following script?

```
 os.system("start MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe /Session:{}".format(parameter1))
 os.system("start MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe /Session:{}".format(parameter2))
 os.system("start MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe /Session:{}".format(parameter3))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module is the preferred way of running child processes. `.run()` function will wait for the command to complete:

```py
import subprocess

for p in (parameter1, parameter2, parameter3):
    subprocess.run(["MSSQL2PostgreSQLPro_Cons.exe", f"/Session:{p}"], check=True)
```